# Can't close as suitable for other sites on SE?

Tags: support

I've been meaning to raise this for a while, and it got to me today.

I'm sure previously you used to be able to vote to close, choose "more suitable for another site on the SE network" and select the other site.  However, when I do that now, all it shows me is meta.travel.SE.  If I want to say, vote to migrate a question to cooking, it isn't giving me the option. And I'm sure it used to, no?

Comment: Was that maybe a moderator-only thing?

Comment: @Gagravarr yeah as we're discussing on the answer below, it may have been :/

Comment: I have seen that also, and have been disappointed at the lack of options.

Answer (score 7):

Migration paths are only provided if they're going to see regular use. For uncommon or unusual migrations, you're better off just flagging it for a moderator, who can still migrate any question to any other site.

(Of course, *Don't Migrate Crap* always applies as a general rule.)

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I'm just starting to doubt my memory of being able to do it. Maybe it was a temporary thing once, or possibly just recalling when I was a moderator.  :P

Comment: @MarkMayo I'm pretty sure it's only true for moderators.

Comment: That's a shame, if voted on as the community it'd actually be pretty useful :/

Comment: I think you just need to close as other and write it in by hand, that seems to work when I've come across the need

Answer (score 2):

SO and SU for example offer "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" (under off-topic because ...) and then below that SO offers five options. We only have the one option: TSE.meta.

I very much doubt users (rather than mods) have ever been able to target a specific site, not a pre-set option, either from TSE or any other SE site.

Comment: it needs a drop down with predictive text

Comment: Also see the more recent *[Add Aviation to migration targets for off-topic questions](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3658/)*

Comment: Graduated sites, like this one, can request new migration paths on meta. We enable them on an as-needed basis, though, and right now there's only place that's even halfway worth considering: Expats, which receives a bit under one migration from here every three days. (But Expats itself is still un-graduated.) Other sites simply don't see migration-worthy questions asked here, and the mods can handle the rare exceptions through flags.